# Не обрабатывается или не отправляется post запрос

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Поставлена задача сделать поисковик вот такого [плана](http://www.valest-russia.ru/catalog). Стал решать вопрос методом Javascript и php. Вот, собственно, сам код:

search.php

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
 <div class="optionCatergory Aged">
  <h4>Старая</h4>
  <?php if($_POST["Aged"]=="1"){ ?>
   <label class='searchClick active'><input type='radio' name='Aged' checked='checked' value='1'>Да</label>
  <?php }else{ ?>
   <label class='searchClick active'><input type='radio' name='Aged' value='1'>Да</label>
  <?php } 
  if($_POST["Aged"]=="0"){ ?>
   <label class='searchClick'><input type='radio' name='Aged' value='0'>Нет</label>
  <?php }else{ ?>
   <label class='searchClick'><input type='radio' name='Aged' value='0'>Нет</label>
  <?php } ?>
 </div>
<input value="Найти" type="submit" class="submitButton">
</form>
```

Вот jQuery:

```
jQuery('.optionCatergory .searchClick').click(function(){
        jQuery('.inshop_filter form .submitButton').click();
```

Но после клика на любой из label (если это радио-кнопка или чекбокс) запрос не отправляется. Если сделать get запрос, то запросы просто не отображаются. Причем текстовый тип работает. Может кто-то что-то подсказать? Те два ответа, которые были даны, не подошли.

Comment: http://tsya.ru

Comment: Забыли запятые расставить, вопрос понял, только с надцатого раза прочтения вопроса

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я бы также советовал использовать 
`$(document).on('click','.searchClick', function(event) {});`
А вообще Вы можете попробовать сохранять состояние выбора при помощи query string, например:

```
http://domain.com/page?select=2
```

где select - некий идентификатор выбранного состояния. А при загрузке парсить query string и выставлять состояние

Comment: нет, не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.searchClick').live('click', function() { this.form.submit(); });
```

Comment: Это если я верно смог понять формулировку вопроса.

Comment: Live устарел сто лет назад, как и delegate. Когда я еще активно ковырялся в js, он уже был объявлен устаревшим и вместо него был введен on.

Comment: Не работает, учитывая, что я live  на on заменил.

Comment: @Etki, не спорю, просто старая вредная привычка, которая пока не подводила :) хотя, избавляться пора...

Comment: у меня на новом jQuery уже не работает